# How to see users of a python package?

Tags: python, python-module

I have made a python package named 'Panclus' but I do not know if anyone is using this package or not. Please tell me how to see how many people have installed my python package. Is it possible to get the name of users?

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/analyzing-pypi-package-downloads/#background):

> PyPI does not display download statistics for a number of reasons:
>
> - Inefficient to make work with a Content Distribution Network (CDN):
>   Download statistics change constantly. Including them in project
>   pages, which are heavily cached, would require invalidating the cache
>   more often, and reduce the overall effectiveness of the cache.
> - Highly inaccurate: A number of things prevent the download counts from
>   being accurate, some of which include:
>
>   - pip’s download cache (lowers download counts)
>   - Internal or unofficial mirrors (can both raise or lower download
>     counts)
>   - Packages not hosted on PyPI (for comparisons sake)
>   - Unofficial scripts or attempts at download count inflation (raises
>     download counts)
>   - Known historical data quality issues (lowers download counts)
> - Not particularly useful: Just because a project has been downloaded a
>   lot doesn’t mean it’s good; Similarly just because a project hasn’t
>   been downloaded a lot doesn’t mean it’s bad!

Get more information about download statistics from [this](https://packaging.python.org/guides/analyzing-pypi-package-downloads/#analyzing-pypi-package-downloads).